# Iphone SDK Record And Play iPod Music

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, audio-recording, ios5

I am currently in the middle of wringing an app for the IOS, their app has code to sample the level of the volume by recording the audio from the microphone to /dev/null which i deletes it immediately, but as well as this i need to be able to play the iPod music at the same time. Because of the recording that is going on the music is stopped and can not be started again.

I have looked at the apple development documentation and so far i have not been able to understand, so would be grateful if not just a like was posted.

Would any one be able to look at the code below and tell me where i am going wrong, or tell me another way to take the audio level that does not make the iDevice stop playing music.

```
- (void)startAudioSampler {

//Check to see if the sampler is already set.
if (audioSampler == nil) {

    //It is not set up, so set it up.
    //Set up the location as it needs to save as a recording, so save it to /dev/null which should delete straight away.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];

    //Set up the settings for the sampler.
    NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                              nil];
    //Create the error for it to report to.
    NSError *error;

    //Create the sampler.
    audioSampler = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];
    //Check it set up correctly.
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
    if (audioSampler != nil) {
        //Start the sampler.
        [audioSampler prepareToRecord];
        audioSampler.meteringEnabled = YES;
        [audioSampler record];

        //Set to sampler every 0.03 seconds (by running the updateInputAudioLevel every 0.03 seconds).
        samplerUpdateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.03 target:self selector:@selector(updateInputAudioLevel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    } else {
        //There was an error during the set up so report it to the log.
        NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help
Thomas